# If statement on variables for insert into table php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a number of variables which are being inserted into the mysql table, on one of my variables I need to insert it into another table, is there a way to say `if $x = y then 'a' else 'b'` within the Insert statement?

Comment: just prepare your query ahead of time with whatever business logic you need.

Comment: Inserting different data into the same table is achievable. Inserting into in an other table as well, is either a trigger, or an other insert statement. Conditionally inserting into another table is just wrapping the extra insert statement with an If. A decent example of what you want to happen would help us give you a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different variable for the result, then use it in the query.

```
$tmp = ($x == 'y' ? 'a' : 'b'); /* if $x==y then $tmp = a else $tmp = b */
$q = "INSERT INTO tbl SET coloumn = $tmp";
```

Comment: @Jez : this might help u better understand things => http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4

Answer (score 1):

Even if your question seems not very clear to me: have you thought about doing this logic in your code instead of an insert statement?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do this within the query. You would include the if statement with 2 different queries based on if the statement evaluated to if or else.

Or you could provide an if statement that resulted in the value of $ x changing. Then include $ x within your query.